# Unblock-File - Why do I need to open a new session?

Tags: powershell

I am using Carbon's Powershell module for some work. When I move the folder to a different machine, the scripts within are flagged and blocked from being executed until I unblock them (which is fine). When I execute the following:

```
gci .\Carbon -Recurse | Unblock-File
```

I am still unable to import the module until I create a new Powershell session. The files are definitely unblocked at this point, but I continue to receive the same error until that new session has been created.

I've read over some technet articles and they state that you just need to close and open Powershell to resolve it, but no reasoning as to why this needs to occur.

Comment: maybe you can wipe stream data as a workaroud ? `gci .\Carbon -Recurse | set-Content $_ -Stream zone.identifier -Value ''`

Comment: Although this method also unblocks the files, it still requires me to create a new PS session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually goes back to the .Net framework on which PowerShell is based. You're essentially loading a new assembly into the process. A blocked file is considered a "remote" file and by default .net is not set to load them.

[How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720133.aspx)

> 2. [Checks whether the assembly name has been bound to before](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720657.aspx) and, if so, uses the previously loaded assembly.

The thing is, this step caches "negative" loading as well (at least in my experience, from trying to load other assemblies). .Net doesn't have a way unload assemblies once they're loaded, so you have no other choice than to restart the process.